# Event handler on Excel.CalculationState starts calculating - Office js

Tags: excel, office-js

Currently the api supports an event handler ([onCalculated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events)) that is being fired when the calculation finishes but is there any way to detect when it actually started?

I have a task pane add-in and I would like to block the interaction while there is ongoing calculations but I'm struggling to detect when they started.

[image].

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your information. The Webadd-in is different from VSTO add-in, web-addin is running in different process, therefore all events that we provided in office.js are **after** event.

May I know what's your scenario? we would like to learn more information that you want to detect when they started.

Comment: When there's ongoing calculations (we work with some heavy worksheets with multiple tabs with pivots updating based on a dataset loaded by the add-in) subsequent interaction with the add-in crashes it (trying to load a new dataset for example). Therefore I'm trying to disable any interaction with the add-in while the calculation state is busy.